# Newton's second law - local laws and non-local laws

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, definition, causality, locality, non-locality

What are local laws? I was reading this line in a book...

> Newtons second law is a local law. This means that it applies to a particle at a particular instant without taking into consideration any history of the particle or it's motion.

What does this mean in simpler terms?

Are their non local laws as well? Please explain with an example.

I'm a high school student.

Comment: Force is associated with its point of application. The object carries no memory of forces applied previously and accelerates according to the force applied at an instance of time. A simple restatement: if force is applied on body A for some time interval, then only body A will accelerate during that interval of time only

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic If you're asking about the book, it's Cengage Mechanics-1, page 6.3. Probably not a common book, you can look at the edit, i elaborated what was written.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlocality#:~:text=Nonlocality%20may%20refer%20to%3A,of%20action%20at%20a%20distance) non locality refers to action from a distance so a simple example can be gravity

Comment: @khaxan here when the term local was used, it was used with reference to laws (N2) and not force, although, yes, gravity could be an example of " non local _force_ " . i don't understand what non local law would be though.

Comment: Did you ask your high school teacher?

Comment: i was reading an outside reference book for curiosity. since local laws isn't in the syllabus so my teacher most likely won't answer it, as he has done in the past. He says stick to the syllabus and understand whatever is in it and don't waste your time on other things before an exam.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two examples. First a local law and then a non-local law, explaining each with examples to make it much simpler.

Ok Local laws, such as Newton's second law for a car, tell you how fast the car accelerates at a particular moment if you know its current mass and the applied force. In contrast for non-local laws  such as the gravitational law for two planets in space, consider not only how they are positioned at a given moment but also how their masses and positions continuously affect their orbits over time. The past is also important for these calculations.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: so you mean that since the gravitation law or say the coulombs law consider the relative distance between the planets or particles, which is governed by what forces were acting in the past, they are non local laws

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. From my understanding non-local laws also consider how the object has evolved over time taking into account all the forces, influences that have acted upon it in the past and will affect it in the future. In contrast local laws describe how an object behaves right now, given its current conditions.

Comment: well the formula of force of gravitation law tells us that it just depends upon the masses and distance between the two masses at any given point of time. so how does it care about what happened in the past?

Comment: if i understand it correctly, the system of 2 planets has "evolved" in the sense that the distance would be varying because of other forces/other gravitational forces acting by other planets/moons.